# How to use sql substring function in a $X{IN} expression?

Tags: sql, jasper-reports

I have a query at report that not working after adding `substring` at `$X{}` expression.

```sql
SELECT t1.grn
FROM qc_master t1
WHERE $X{IN, t1.i_rep_no.substring(0,1), type}
```

I am getting the error `Parameter 1 does not exist` during preview at *iReport*/*JSS*. How to fix this?

Comment: Yes. but didnt reach solution yet. Could you please tell me how to use substring inside IN clause of jasper report sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicating the answer from [Jaspersoft Community](http://community.jaspersoft.com//questions/1047186/how-use-substring-notinin-clause):

> You cannot use an SQL function inside a JasperReports $X clause function as per: http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/query/index.html#clause_functions
>
> Instead, you could have something like this in your SQL:
>
> `and substr(t1.i_rep_no,1,1) IN ($P!{type})`
>
> with parameter `type` as a `java.lang.String` with comma separated values, or as anything that resolves to that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable input. Got expected result.